# Error except ErrorValue y except python 3.10

Tags: python

al querer ejecutar el siguiente codigo:

```
while True:
    elegir_numero = int(input("Escriba el numero: "))
    try:
        if elegir_numero == 1 or elegir_numero == 2 or elegir_numero == 3:
            print("a")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('"' + str(elegir_numero) + '"' + " no es un numero")
    except elegir_numero > 3:
        print('"' + str(elegir_numero) + '"' + "no es un numero elegible")
```

cuando por ejemplo ejecuto una letra me sale el siguiente error:

> Escriba el numero: i
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\echea\OneDrive\Programación\prueba.py", line 13, in < module >
>
> elegir_numero = int(input("Escriba el numero: "))
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'

pero no me sale el mensaje que deberia salir en except ValueError, y con el ultimo except tambien es lo mismo, solo que no me sale nada solo se pasa se largo, asi:

> Escriba el numero: 6
>
> Escriba el numero: 7
>
> Escriba el numero: 4

Cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchos errores. La versión correcta es:

```
while True:
    try:
        entrada = input("Escriba el numero: ")
        elegir_numero = int(entrada)
        if elegir_numero == 1 or elegir_numero == 2 or elegir_numero == 3:
            print("a")
            break
        else:
            print('"' + entrada + '"' + "no es un numero elegible")
    except ValueError:
        print('"' + entrada + '"' + " no es un numero")
```

Primero, si el usuario ingresa un no-numero, se genera una excepción `ValueError`, pero como el `int(input())` no está dentro del `try-except`, la excepción la atrapa Python y te aparece el error de marras.

Segundo, dentro del `except` no puedes hacer uso de `elegir_numero`, pues nunca se llegó a generar. Solución: guarda el ingreso en una variable de texto y luego conviertela:

```
        entrada = input("Escriba el numero: ")
        elegir_numero = int(entrada)
```

De esa manera puedes escribir correctamente la acción:

```
        print('"' + str(entrada) + '"' + " no es un numero")
```

Finalmente,

```
except elegir_numero > 3:
    print('"' + str(elegir_numero) + '"' + "no es un numero elegible")
```

los `except` son para manejar excepciones, y `elegir_numero > 3` no lo es; debes trasladar la excepción dentro del `try-except`

Comment: gracias <3, y como hago para por ejemplo:
en ves de poner:  if elegir_numero == 1 or elegir_numero == 2, etc   hago para que esten en una misma variable, osea:    if_numero == 1,2,3,4,5,6,etc porque con la primera forma resulta mucho codigo

Comment: @UnHUmano `if elegir_numero in range(1, 7) es `True` si `elegir_numero` está entre 1 y 6 (uno menos el límite).

Comment: y si por ejemplo quiero que sean los numeros: 1821, 2, 134, 13, 9, 0, 18

Comment: `if numero in [1821, 2, 134, ... ]`. Te convendria leer al menos el tutorial de Python.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda <3